# GLSL shader not compiling on android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl

This shader fails to compile on android, but works flawlessly on Windows. 
I'm using libGDX and I'm pretty new to shaders, so I have no idea what's going on.
If it does matter - LG F60 with Adreno 305 was used.

Fragment:

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform float time;

uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;
uniform vec4 u_neon;



void main() {
 vec4 color = texture2D(u_sampler2D, v_texCoord0) * v_color;



  float cx = (gl_FragCoord.x / 100) + 0.5*sin(time/5);
  float cy = ( gl_FragCoord.y  / 10) + 0.5*cos(time/3);


   color.r = sin(0.24*((gl_FragCoord.x/100)*sin(time/3)+(gl_FragCoord.y/100)*cos(time/5))+time) - sin(sqrt(0.3*(cx*cx+time*cy)+1)+time);

 color.b =  color.r * 0.5 + sin(sqrt(0.3*(cx*cx+cy*cy)+1)+time);

 color.g = color.r - sin(sqrt(0.004*(cx*cx+cy*cy)+1)+time);
color.a = 1;


  gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Vertex:

```
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;


void main(void) {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);

}
```

Logcat:

```
01-12 20:11:14.777: I/System.out(15485): ERROR: 0:16: '/' :  wrong operand types  no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
01-12 20:11:14.777: I/System.out(15485): ERROR: 0:16: '/' :  wrong operand types  no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'uniform float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
01-12 20:11:14.777: I/System.out(15485): ERROR: 0:17: '/' :  wrong operand types  no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
01-12 20:11:14.787: I/System.out(15485): ERROR: 0:17: '/' :  wrong operand types  no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'uniform float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
01-12 20:11:14.787: I/System.out(15485): ERROR: 0:20: '/' :  wrong operand types  no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
01-12 20:11:14.787: I/System.out(15485): ERROR: 0:20: '/'
01-12 20:11:14.867: W/Adreno-ES20(15485): <core_glTexParameteriv:566>: GL_INVALID_ENUM
```

Comment: The OpenGL shaders are being compiled (effectively) by the GPU-specific device driver in the system, so you can run into all sorts of platform-specific behavior.  See http://bitiotic.com/blog/2013/09/24/opengl-es-shading-language-potholes-and-problems/ for some Libgdx+Android+OpenGL+Shader pitfalls.

Comment: And always use a `#version` pragma: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_%28GLSL%29#Version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            vvvvvvvvvvvvvv float            vvvv ditto
float cx = (gl_FragCoord.x / 100) + 0.5*sin(time/5);
                             ^^^ int             ^ ditto
```

GLSL ES 1.0 won't automatically promote `int`s to `float`s and is a stickler for type compatibility.

Try something like this:

```
float cx = (gl_FragCoord.x / 100.0) + 0.5*sin(time/5.0);
                             ^^^^^ float           ^^^ ditto
```

Comment: There are some GPU's that will cast them to floats automatically, even though it's not in the GLES spec. This can be a "gotcha" if you happen to test on a device that does this. It's a good idea to check the log after compiling a shader (`shaderProgram.getLog()`) and fix any warnings in case the warnings are errors on some other device.